# How to successfully wait for a directory (that was open in explorer) to be deleted and re-created?

Tags: c#

I'm running into a bit of an issue. I'm not exactly sure if this is a bug or I'm just simply missing something but here we go..

I have this code (inside a Task):

```
var root = Path.Combine("somepath", "someotherpath");
if (Directory.Exists(root))
    Directory.Delete(root, true);
Directory.CreateDirectory(root);

foreach (var something in somethingelse) {
    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
    using (var s = new FileStream(somepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        await s.WriteAsync(m.ToArray(), 0, m.ToArray().Length);
}
```

My problem is if "**root**" is open in explorer, I get a

> "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path ' some file path using "**root**" '.'

@ this line of code:

```
 using (var s = new FileStream(somepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

Now if I **DON'T** have "**root**" open in explorer, I don't get any exceptions.

I'm stumped..

Comment: What if the value of `somepath` and `someotherpath` and `root`?

Comment: @mjwills 
**root** is a combination of **desktop** and **1.0.0.0** where **somepath** is just **C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Dummy\1.0.0.0\74ad6189-3a1b-4b19-88cd-b99dc0a1b6fc.txt**

Comment: Rather than deleting and recreating the directory, have you considered deleting the _contents_ of the directory?

Comment: @mjwills if it needs to be done I guess I wont have a choice. I just find it weird that if **1.0.0.0** is open in explorer and deleted, explorer switches back to the **Dummy** directory and the new **1.0.0.0** directory doesn't get created even though **Directory.CreateDirectory** is executed without exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**Final Fix:**

> My problem was if the directory to be deleted was open in explorer, I would get exceptions even though i was **re-creating** it after deletion without any errors.
>
> As suggested, I could simply delete the contents of the target directory and continue. Which I've tested and worked but me being me, instead of just deleting its contents, I **DELETE>CREATE** still.. but add this code before executing the call to **FileStream**:

```
if (false == Directory.Exists(root))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(root);

using (var s = new FileStream(somepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
```

> Adding the code above, I don't need to delete any folder contents and I'm exception free. Though, if you do have the folder open, you'll need to refresh it. Thanks to the users who helped.

Comment: `if (!Directory.Exists(root))`